# Как обработать телефонный номер python

Tags: python

Мучаюсь и не понимаю, к делу. Есть код который должен вывести какой оператор у номера телефона

```
phone = '0501177711'

if int(phone[0]) == 0:


        if int(phone[1:3]) == 67 or 68 or 96 or 97 or 98:

            operator = 'Киевстар'

        elif int(phone[1:3]) == 50 or 66 or 95 or 99:

            operator = 'Vodafone'

        elif int(phone[1:3]) == 63 or 73 or 93:

            operator = 'Lifecell'
```

Ответ: Киевстар, хотя должно выбить водафон и так уже полтора часа сижу. В чём проблема может быть? Я пробовал и str и int приравнивать но не выходит

Comment: не надо делать таких конструкций с `or`, если вы не уверены в приоритете сравнения (у вас оно неверное). сделайте так, например: `if int(phone[1:3]) in [67, 68, 96, 97, 98]:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kowl так ты пишешь одно условие: `int(phone[1:3]) == 67`, а дальше одни or идут, так же нельзя делать, ты по сути строишь условия типа ЧИСЛО ИЛИ ЧИСЛО. Ты пиши тогда `int(phone[1:3]) == 67 or int(phone[1:3]) == 96`. Но лучше вообще просто сделать так: `if int(phone[1:3]) in (67, 68, 96, 97, 98)`

upd: Можно писать и так, по идее, должно быть быстрее:

```
if phone.startswith(('67', '68', '96'), 1, 3)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, да не подумал что-то. В любом случае спасибо что помог

Comment: @Kowl пожалуйста, отметь только ответ правильным. И чекни upd, там полезный метод, думаю, он будет быстрее и читабельнее

Answer (score 1):

У вас первое же условие всегда True. Так как там:

```
    int(phone[1:3]) == 67 или 68==True (и т.д).
```